# How to use external javascript onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, dashboard

I am using the free version of ArchitectUI (https://dashboardpack.com/live-demo-free/?livedemo=329) to create an website.
I want to make a button that expands the Menu on the left side.
When i try to use the Chrome-DevTools on-mouse-click option, i can see the following output:

[image]

Line 39 is being called when i press the arrow down button on the Menu to make it expand.

```
I pasted the output from line 39 here: https://pastebin.com/X9qt0SMW
```

How can I make a
”Click me" that uses this function from the main.js file included with this dashboard?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify ur question a little? 
Right now I understand a little.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to paste some code but it screwed up the layout. I want to make u button that, when clicked on, expands the menu (the same when i press the arrow down button in the live demo)

Comment: I looked up the whole file but the function that does is nowhere to be found. But, you can do it using simple js and CSS. When a user clicks the menu btn then you can use css classes and states to show and hide the menu bar.